# Is there a delay in when someone changes their sharing settings in facebook and when their information shows in graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am not seeing the birthday in the graph api explorer, but can see it on the facebook web UI.

Assuming that I have requested and the user has accepted the appropriate permissions, if someone had their birthday privacy setting to "Only Me" and then changed it to "Public" how long should I expect to have to wait before that person's birthday shows up in the facebook-graph-api?

Comment: It does not matter what the privacy setting for birthday is on facebook.com – if you want to read it via API, you have to request `user_birthday` permission from them.

Comment: Thanks CBroe.  If that's the case, then why can I see the birthday on a friend's facebook page, but can't see it in when I look up their user in the facebook graph api explorer and I have granted the 'friends_birthday' permission to the api explorer app?  Is it different when you are looking up friends?

Comment: Your friends can choose which info they are willing to share with apps their friends are using. So that I give your app permission to read my friends’ birthdays does not mean that my friends are willing to give that info to the app I am using. https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share

Comment: That is exactly what I needed CBroe.  It fixed my issue.  Thank you!  If you post a response referencing your comment I will accept it.